# jQuery out of key-value pair send key to servlet while show value on webpage

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, servlets

I have to replace my `<select>` tag with jQueryUI autocomplete

So initially my code was something like

```
<select id = "product" name = "product">
<option value = "M0001">Mercedes</option>
<option value = "B0001">BMW</option>
<option value = "F0001">Ferrari</option>
</select>
```

So when the form was submitted my servlet would get the value as M0001 or B0001 etc. depending on whether Mercedes or BMW

Now i have to replace it with an jQuery UI autocomplete. such that when i type on `<input type = "text" name = "product"/>` on webpage i will get result as mercedes or BMW etc.
but once BMW is selected. 
On my servlet doing `request.getParameter("product");` will give me B001

How can i do that ??

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: What if i do not want to use a hidden field??? Is there any way ??

Comment: You could change it the value on submit?